# Différence entre « bilan » et « conclusion » dans le cadre d'un rapport ?

Tags: sens

Dans le cadre de la rédaction d'un rapport d'entreprise (stage ou apprentissage), quelle différence faut-t-il faire entre l'écriture du bilan et celle de la conclusion ?

Les deux me sont demandés et la différence entre ces deux mots me semble difficile à distinguer.

Une recherche Google m'emmène sur des résultats tel que :

> Comment rédiger la conclusion d'un rapport de stage ? La conclusion du
>   rapport de stage permet de dresser un bilan global du stage

... ce qui m'embrouille d'autant plus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bilan* s'applique au stage. Le bilan du stage, c'est la liste de ce qui a été fait, produit ou acquis durant le stage. En principe, on peut faire le bilan de quelque chose à tout moment (un bilan de santé, le bilan des comptes d'une entreprise, …), mais en français moderne, le mot a souvent tendance à évoquer quelque chose qu'on fait à la fin (ce qui se justifie dans la mesure où beaucoup de bilans décrivent l'historique de quelque chose et pas seulement la situation présente).

*Conclusion* s'applique au rapport. La conclusion d'un texte, c'est la dernière partie, qui résume le contenu en se concentrant sur ce qu'il est le plus important de retenir, et donne éventuellement des pistes de lecture pour la suite.

On peut dire que le rapport de stage en entier fait le bilan du stage. Mais le rapport est plus détaillé que ce que l'on attend en général d'un bilan ; donc on dit plutôt que la conclusion du rapport, qui résume le rapport, est un bilan du stage.

On peut aussi appliquer le mot *conclusion* au stage, mais dans ce cas il désigne la dernière partie, ce qu'on fait à la fin : c'est donc l'écriture du rapport, ou peut-être la soutenance.

Answer (score 3):

*Conclusion* a dans tes exemples le sens de "fin, ce sur quoi on conclut" (il peu aussi avoir le sens de "résultat, déduction", qui est souvent sous-entendu, et peut être pertinent). *Bilan* se rapproche d'*inventaire*: l'ensemble des faits et statistiques nécessaires à l'évaluation de la situation.

Comment: Autrement dit, la conclusion est le *quoi* tandis que le bilan est le *comment* ?

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que dans le cas d'un stage, le bilan est effectivement plus quantitatif. Ce qui a été réalisé durant le stage (actions, développement, etc.). C'est donc effectivement plus une sorte d'inventaire.

La conclusion devrait contenir des arguments plus qualitatifs. A-t-on répondu aux besoins de l'entreprise, a-t-on résolu le problème donné, avec quelle efficacité ? La conclusion, permet de faire ressortir que les diverses réalisations (données dans le bilan) ont permis de résoudre le problème, et avec quel degré de satisfaction par rapport à d'éventuelles contraintes de départ.